# How can i improve Auto complete %LIKE%

Tags: php, autocomplete

From data base i have student record like this:
[image]

Hallticket name **S22J79** (S-student J-job).

This  Hall-ticket created based on `studentid` and `jobid`.

Now i have a Autocomplete functionality to retrieve the particular student based on `student_fname` and `student_lname` and `student_pid`

My question is how can i retrieve the student data based on total hallticket number

this is my code:

```
$studentsQuery =$conn->query('
select s.student_fname as label,i.email,s.student_pid,s.student_email,s.student_fname,
s.student_lname,s.profile_pic 
from 
   r_job_invitations i 
 LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_students s 
 ON 
   i.email = s.student_email 
 where 
    i.id_job = "'.$job_id.'" and 
    student_fname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" OR
    student_lname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" OR 
    student_pid LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" ');
```

> i am able to get student details if i type "22" then Mohammad waheed
>   is coming **but** when i type total hall-ticket number i.e `S22J79` it
>   is not coming even the key word consist "22" in it how can i tell
>   system to read that "22" from hall ticket number..?

so is there any advance level of **%LIKE%**..?

Comment: If you know that hallticket ``S22J79`` is constructed from studentid and jobid, what keeps you from splitting ``S22J79`` and extracting studentid and then search with studentid?

Comment: First of all I recomend you use LOWER() and strtolower() functions.

Comment: @mpf82 can u tell me how can i split.. ?  i tried this but concatination error.! `student_pid LIKE "'"S".$keysearch."J".$jobid.'%"`

Comment: @Maytyn sure it helped me as well thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the code they are searching is ALWAYS S{student_id}J{job_id}
then do this:

```
$codeSearch = preg_replace("/(S)|(J.*)/","",$keysearch);
$studentsQuery =$conn->query('
select s.student_fname as label,i.email,s.student_pid,s.student_email,s.student_fname,
s.student_lname,s.profile_pic 
from 
   r_job_invitations i 
 LEFT JOIN 
   tbl_students s 
 ON 
   i.email = s.student_email 
 where 
    i.id_job = "'.$job_id.'" and 
    student_fname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" OR
    student_lname LIKE "'.$keysearch.'%" OR 
    student_pid LIKE "'.$codeSearch.'%"');
```

this way you can find student 22 if the user only typed "S2" which I think is the point right?

Comment: Exactly..! Wow it worked like a magic thank you so much. where can i find the documentation related `preg_replace(`

Comment: preg replace uses regex, so http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php and https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/ are good places to start